# Pass std::max_element() or std::min_element() to function as argiment

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to pass `std::max_element()` or `std::min_element()` to template class method? For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithms>

template <typename T>
class A 
{
public: 
    int fooMax()
    {
        return foo(std::max_element());
    }

    int fooMin()
    {
        return foo(std::min_element());
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;

private:
    int foo(??? func)
    {
        auto it = func(data_.begin(), data_.end());

        int i = do_something();
        return i;
    }
};
```

I tried to use function pointers, but it did not compiled.

Comment: If you wanted to pass a function pointer, you'd have to instantiate the template manually. But that may incur indirection costs and prevent inlining, so the better solution is to pass a functor (perhaps one that you must define yourself) and make `foo` a template, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::max_element` and `std::min_element` are template functions, and you need to instantiate them:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    int fooMax()
    {
        return foo(&std::max_element<typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator>);
    }

    int fooMin()
    {
        return foo(&std::min_element<typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator>);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;

private:
    template<typename func_type>
    int foo(func_type func)
    {
        auto it=func(data_.begin(), data_.end());

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Tested with gcc 5.3.1 with `-std=c++14`.

You may also choose to instantiate a `std::vector<T>::iterator` instead, if you so choose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lambda expressions for this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A {
   vector<T> v;
   A(vector<T> v): v(v) { }
   template <class Lambda>
   T element(Lambda &&lambda) {
      return *lambda(v.begin(), v.end());
   }
};

int main() {
   vector<int> vi {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   A<int> a(vi);
   cout << a.element([](typename vector<int>::iterator begin,
                        typename vector<int>::iterator end){ 
                            return max_element(begin, end); 
                        }) << endl;
}
```

This way it should get inlined and thus efficient...

If you can use c++14 code would get even simpler:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A {
   vector<T> v;
   A(vector<T> v): v(v) { }
   T element(auto &&lambda) {
      return *lambda(v.begin(), v.end());
   }
};

int main() {
   vector<int> vi {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   A<int> a(vi);
   cout << a.element([](auto begin, auto end) { 
                           return max_element(begin, end); 
                        }) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

not what you want to see, I know. But if you want to pass it as a function pointer...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int do_something();

template <typename T>
class A 
{
public: 
    int fooMax()
    {
        return foo(std::max_element<const_iterator>);
    }

    int fooMin()
    {
        return foo(std::min_element<const_iterator>);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;

private:
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
  using fp = const_iterator (*)(const_iterator, const_iterator);


    int foo(fp func)
    {
        auto it = func(data_.begin(), data_.end());

        int i = do_something();
        return i;
    }
};
```